# How to cast back an object with a linq query inside it with more than 1 entity?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following scenario. One [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) query with a join statment:

```
public Object getMGM(int MEB_Id)
{
    var unitOfWork = new DAL.Implementations.Entity_Framework.UnitOfWork<dbgmEntities>();

    var queryRoles =  from a in unitOfWork._ctx.MembrosMGM
                          join b in unitOfWork._ctx.Membros on a.MGM_Pai equals b.MEB_Id
                          where a.MGM_Filho == MEB_Id
                          select new { b.MEB_Nome, b.MEB_Id, a.MGM_Familiar };

    return queryRoles;
}
```

`queryRoles` is running inside a thread. So, I only have to return it as an object. But I cannot find a way to cast it and get the `{ b.MEB_Nome, b.MEB_Id, a.MGM_Familiar }` of the select. I tried the following code with one Entity set on the return and it works fine, but if I have more than 1 entity on the same linq query i don't know how to cast it back:

```
//this one works fine if i have just one entity set (DAL.MembroResponsavel)
var queryMembroResponsaveis = ((IEnumerable)smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(x => editMeb.getMembroResponsavel(currentId)).Result).Cast<DAL.MembroResponsavel>().ToList();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those having the same problem returning an Anonymous Type I created a class that gets its return values:

```
public class MemberGetaMember
{
    public int MEB_Id {get;set;}
    public string MEB_Nome { get; set;}
    public bool? MGM_Familiar { get; set; }
}
```

Then i can cast it back on the return:

```
foreach (var x in queryRoles)
            list.Add(new MemberGetaMember { MEB_Id = x.MEB_Id, MEB_Nome = x.MEB_Nome, MGM_Familiar = x.MGM_Familiar });

        return list;
```

This question helped me how to figure this out

[How to return query results from method that uses LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075770/how-to-return-query-results-from-method-that-uses-linq-to-sql)

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Note that anonymous objects are specifically designed to only be used from the scope in which they were created; they weren't designed to be returned from the method that created them.  The easiest, simplest, and most appropriate solution in virtually all cases is to create a new named type, as you have done here.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to enumerate the results and cast to a list:

```
var queryRoles =  (from a in unitOfWork._ctx.MembrosMGM
                  join b in unitOfWork._ctx.Membros on a.MGM_Pai equals b.MEB_Id
                  where a.MGM_Filho == MEB_Id
                  select new { b.MEB_Nome, b.MEB_Id, a.MGM_Familiar }).ToList();
```

Comment: the problem is when i cast back this query :/ .ToList() on the source doesn't work.